# If we were to arrange 'SCHOOL' to form 3-letters word, it can be arranged in how many ways?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

From the letter 'SCHOOL', how many three-letter words that you can arrange? Just to be clear, we are talking about "arrange" not "pick". And we do not really care whether the three-letter words have meaning or not.

Is my solution correct as I dont have answer for this question?

Case with 0 'O' : 4P3=24

Case with 1 'O' : 4C2*3=18

Case with 2 'O's: 4C1*2=8

Total = 24+18+8=60

My final answer would be 60 according to the cases stated above, is this correct? Or I did miss something else?

Comment: Your second and third cases are wrong and the answer should be $72$. By the way $^5P_3$ gives you all $3$ letter words without repetition of letters (combined cases 1 and 2). Then add $4 \cdot 3$ for words with two $O's$.

Answer (score 1):

In the second case you have to choose two letters from {S,C,H,L} and one 'O' and you can
arrange them in 4C2*3!=36 ways

In the third case you can choose 1 letter from the remaining 4 letters S, C, H, L in 4C1 ways.

After that the two 'O's could be arranged in 3 ways :-

- |  |O|O|
- |O|  |O|
- |O|O|  |

You could place the third letter in any of the 3 ways.
So with 2 'O', you could make 4*3=12 words.

So the total number of words would be 24+36+12=72

Answer (score 0):

The case $3$ is not correct. You should multiply by $3$ instead of $2.
$

Answer (score 0):

No, your second and third cases are wrong. For the second case, you should get $\binom {4}{2} 3!$ , and for the third case you should get $\binom {4}{1} 3$.

Answer (score 0):

For the case with $1 'O'$, you need to multiply $3!$ instead of $3$, which gives you $36$. And in the next case you need to multiply $\frac{3!}{2!}$, giving you $12$.

So the total should probably be: $$24+36+12=72$$